# Dont work Link in textView When i read html data

Tags: android, html, unicode, textview

I hava a textView that i set text  it from a html format but when my data is unicode , link in it dont work ;

```
content_str = "  لینک متن دانلود "
                + "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">اینجاست</a> " + "این است.";
showTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(content_str));
```

but when i add a char for example a at first link in it work

```
content_str ="a"+ "  لینک متن دانلود "
                + "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">اینجاست</a> " + "این است.";
```

showTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(content_str));

Please help me

Comment: have you tried utf-8, as far as i know your language is right-to-left so maybe there is some EOF to prevent that being working, and when you put `a` it moves the EOF to left so your text can work

Answer (score 0):

If you want the link works, try this:

```
content_str ="a"+ "  لینک متن دانلود "
            + "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">اینجاست</a> " + "این است.";
showTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(content_str));
showTxt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: i used it , but dont work ; when i add a char to first my link  work .